# What does it mean when a Chrome extension asks for permissions for 'eth and test sites'?

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, google-chrome-extensions

Metamask asks for permissions to

> Read and change your data on all eth sites and all test sites

What is 'an eth site'? Is it a site with `eth` in its URL?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This extension declares following permissions in its `manifest.json` file:

```
    ["storage","unlimitedStorage","clipboardWrite","http://localhost:8545/","https://*
.infura.io/","activeTab", "webRequest", "*://*.eth/","*://*.test/","notifications"   ],
```

So, it requires access to all .eth and .test websites. TIL .eth is a TLD, just like .com or .org.